# Electric field integral plot

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am trying to plot the electric field integral in Matlab, E(yaxis) Vs Z (xaxis). The function is as follows :

[image]

I would like to graph the very first integral E(z) in this picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have the analytic formula for this integral, you just need to set the values for z and compute the corresponding E(z):

```
%% Set the values for z
z = x1:0.1:x2;
% x1 and x2 are your bounds on the X axis
% The discrete step is set to 0.1, lower/increase it depending on the level of detail you want

%% Compute the electric field values
Ez = (k*l/z) .* ( b/sqrt(z.*z + b*b) + a/sqrt(z.*z + a*a) );

%% Plot the values
plot(z, Ez);
```

Answer (score 1):

That shouldn't be a problem.  Let's assume that some constants are already set before plotting.  That is `a`, `b`, `k` and `lambda`.

Also since you're plotting in MATLAB, you will need discrete steps.... so choose a small step, like `s = 0.01;`.  You will also need a starting point and an ending point for your `z` values (which is already declared as `-a` to `b`).  Therefore, the code would look something like this:

```
  s = 0.01;

  % Define z values
  z = -a : s : b;

  % Ez values
  E = (k*lambda / z) .* ( (b / sqrt(z.^2 + b^2)) + (a / sqrt(z.^2 + a^2)) );

  plot(z, E);
  title('E vs. Z');
```

Hope this works!